# Difference between kCFCalendarUnitDay and NSCalendarUnitDay in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

I would just like to ask what's the difference between kCFCalendarUnitDay and NSCalendarUnitDay in Objective C? I'm planning to use it to fire a local notification on a specific time of the day. I was thinking, which one is more appropriate to use? I hope you could help me chose. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: The documentation for the API you intend to use will tell you the one to use.

Comment: The prefix CF vs NS is also a good hint. Turning on compiler warnings will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSCalendarUnitDay is being used in Foundation Framework

kCFCalendarUnitDay is being used in Core Foundation Framework

CF Means "Core Foundation"

k represents the constants. That is Apple's Convention while representing constant

NSCalendarUnitDay constant is initialised from the Core Foundation Framework's "kCFCalendarUnitDay" constant.

**They both same & representing the same constant.**

**I would recommend you to use Foundation Framework's NSCalendarUnitDay**

Refer the attached screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks bro. Your answer is what I've been looking for. Thanks for the advice.